# How to authorize user in RESTful request?

Tags: web-services, rest, authentication, jboss, authorization

From the posts about REST services, I see that it should **not** be **used sessions** together **with REST**, and with every request there is need to send user credentials to the REST service. But I don't see that somebody continues then how to make the authorization in next requests after login.

In my project, I authenticate (login) the user, checking his credentials from database server.

If with every REST request also comes user credentials again, does this mean that, for any need of authorization after login, I need to check the credentials again from the database?
This means, after login, with almost every click and surfing pages, I need to access to the database to check the user credentials, just like I do it for login.

Or...

Am I missing some thing?

Is there another way to remember in the server side that the user had already logged in before and thus is authorised?

Do I keep some secret key related to the user in the server, and then check this etc.? But, does not this mean keeping a session?

**REST => Not Session => Send credentials with every request**

Does the above mean, **=> Authorize the user just like in the authentication** ?

Or what are other alternatives?

Thank you for clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is the best approach:

> REST => Not Session => Send credentials with every request

Take a look on [OAuth](http://oauth.net/). The version 1.0 may be useful for you.

Spring Security already have implementations for OAuth in Java.

Answer (score 0):

> If with every REST request also comes user credentials again, does this mean that, for any need of authorization after login, I need to check the credentials again from the database?

1. You have to authenticate user on each request, but whether authentication uses database or not depends on implementation. By the way, you also have to then authorize the request for the authenticated user.

> Do I keep some secret key related to the user in the server, and then check this etc.? But, does not this mean keeping a session?

2. You can have some secret key known only to the user as an alternative to username-password pair and use this secret key for authentication.
3. The presence of a secret key doesn't mean keeping a session, because it is not necessarily change on a per session basis.

> In my project, I authenticate (login) the user, checking his credentials from database server.

4. Login is not authentication, it's usually a request for a secret key / session key done using username-password pair for authentication